# Rancher API Call to Determine if a Service Upgrade has Finished

Tags: rancher

Does anyone know if there is a way using the Rancher API to find   out if a service upgraded has completed or failed? We would like to have a notification on when a service upgrade has completed. I have looked though the rancher documentation to try to find this capability to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the upgraded containers are done creating the service's state will change from `upgrading` to `upgraded` and the old ones are stopped.  You can watch the state by polling the `links.self` URL of the service, or through the `/v1/subscribe?eventNames=resource.change` WebSocket.

Once the service is `upgraded` you need to (optionally verify things are happy, then) call the `finishupgrade` action on it (`POST` to the URL in `actions.finishupgrade` on the service).  That will put the state back to `active` and cleanup the old containers.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for this for days! I really appreciate your answer.